# Application on device waiting for debugger

Tags: android-emulator, android

I'm working on an app and I've been able to successfully debug it using the device. I have a crudely working version of the app and I wanted to test it out on the phone, show it to friends and get opinions. The problem is, after doing adb install  I now have the icon on my phone but when I try to launch it, it gives me the "Waiting For Debugger the process is waiting for the debugger to attach" message. I have removed the 'debug=true' flag in the application manifest and also turned off usb debugging on the phone. Why is the application thinking I'm still debugging it? What do I need to do to be able to run it without having debugger on eclipse attached?

Comment: restart your device then try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Set debug="false" in manifest.xml, and uninstall application from your device and reinstall it. It will work

Comment: I have set debug=false (I've already mentioned this in my post), I've uninstalled and re-installed multiple times.

Comment: happen same with me previously, restarted my device, and it worked.. give it as a try

Answer (score 2):

just restart the device, not power off, choose restart

Answer (score 0):

If all the above doesn't work, start the application in debug mode.

1) In eclipse -> go to the debug perspective

2) When the app is running -> press the "Disconnect" button (next to the "stop")

3) Turn off your phone.

4) Remove the battery for 30 sec

All should be back normal

Comment: Restarting device works; Why should you need to remove battery!